# Does writing a dataframe to HDFS affect its sorting

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I'm running a code on apache spark on a multi node environment(one master and two slave nodes) in which I'm manipulating a dataframe and then performing logistic regression to it. In between I'm also writing out the interim transformed files. I have witnessed a peculiar observation (and yes I've double checked and triple checked) which I'm not able to explain and want to confirm if this could be because of my code or there might be other factors in play.

I have a dataframe like

df

```
uid rank text
a   1    najn
b   2    dak
c   1    kksa
c   3    alkw
b   1    bdsj
c   2    asma
```

I sort it with the following code

```
sdf = df.orderBy("uid", "rank")
sdf.show()

uid rank text
a   1    najn
b   1    bdsj
b   2    dak
c   1    kksa
c   2    asma
c   3    alkw
```

and write the transformed df to HDFS using

```
sdf.repartition(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("/someLocation")
```

Now when i again try to view the data it seems to have lost its sorting

```
sdf.show() 
uid rank text
a   1    najn
c   2    asma
b   2    dak
c   1    kksa
c   3    alkw
b   1    bdsj
```

When i skip the writing code, it works fine.

Anyone has any pointers if this might be a valid case and we can do something to resolve it.

P.s. I tried various variations of the writing code, increasing the number of partition, removing the partitioning altogether and saving it to other formats.

Comment: `repartition` shuffles all data obliterating and previous order. Otherwise order should be preserved in the simple output formats like this one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not writing to HDFS but rather the repartition as stated in the comments by zero323.

If you are planning to write everything down to a single file you should do it like this:

sdf.coalesce(1).orderBy("uid", "rank").write...

coalesce avoids repartitioning (it just copies the partitions one after the other instead of shuffling everything by the hash) which would mean your data would still be ordered within the original partitions and therfore faster to order (of course you can always lose the original ordering as it won't help much here).

Note that this is not scalable as you are pulling everything to a single partition. if you would have wrong without any repartitioning you would get a number of files according to the original number of partitions of sdf. Each file would be ordered inside so you can easily combine them.